# How to export a react-native component with styles

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-navigation

I have a Header component which looks like this :

When I try to import this to another component, its spreading to the whole screen. I tried to pass style props and change the height but it isn't working.

In the Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Text, Navigator } from 'react-native';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import SimpleLineIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';

const h = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const w = Dimensions.get('window').width; //360

export default class Header extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
                <View style = {[styles.headerStyle, this.props.style]}>
                    <View style={styles.icon}>
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons.Button iconStyle={styles.icon} backgroundColor="#FDA74A" name="cart-outline" size={25} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.icon}>
                        <FontAwesome.Button iconStyle={styles.icon} backgroundColor="#FDA74A" name="comment-o" size={25} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.icon}>
                        <MaterialIcons.Button iconStyle={styles.icon} backgroundColor="#FDA74A" name="notifications-none" size={25} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.icon}>
                        <MaterialIcons.Button iconStyle={styles.icon} backgroundColor="#FDA74A" name="help-outline" size={25} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.menuStyle}>
                        <SimpleLineIcons.Button backgroundColor="#FDA74A" name="menu" size={25} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')} underlayColor="#FDA74A"/>
                    </View>
                    <View style = {styles.headerTextViewStyle}>
                        <Text text={this.props} style={styles.headerTextStyle}>{this.props.text}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    menuStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
   },
    headerStyle:{
        backgroundColor: '#FDA74A',
        flex: 1,
        width: w,
        height:h/5,
        flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
    },
    icon:{
        marginRight:0,
        marginLeft:0
    },
    headerTextStyle:{
        position:'absolute',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        fontSize: 28,
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        margin: 0.045*w,
    },
    headerTextViewStyle:{
        flexDirection:'column-reverse'
    }
});
```

In the Wallet.js(where I want this Header)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import Header from './Header';

const h = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const w = Dimensions.get('window').width;

export default class Wallet extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style= {styles.containerStyle}>
                <Header style={styles.headerStyle}
                        text="Your Wallet" />

            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    containerStyle:{
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor:'white',
    },
    headerStyle:{
        height:h/5,
    },
});
```

See this Header Image  --> [Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18q2V.png)

**I want a common Header just like shown in the image throughout the application for all of the screens. Please let me know if you know how to do it ?**

Comment: Entire source code for `Header.js` is relevant

Comment: Yeah but I don't know how to import the whole component with styles.

Comment: This may be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678025/how-to-customize-touchableopacity-and-reuse-in-each-component/43680123#43680123

Comment: Thanks, @MattyK14. It looks like a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused due to `flex`. If you notice, you're using `flex: 1` in both the components. Adding a `child component` other than header in **Wallet.js** with greater `flex` value e.g `flex: 3` or `flex: 4` (as per your app UI) may solve the issue.

**UPDATE**

All you have to do is add another component/View in **Wallet.js**

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style= {styles.containerStyle}>
      <Header 
        style={styles.headerStyle}
        text="Your Wallet" 
      />
      <View style={{flex:4}}>
        <Text style: {{fontSize: 18}}>
          Replace your main/body component instead of this view
        </Text>
       </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but do you have any solution to make a common component throughout the app (like the header in my case, you can see the pic above)?

Comment: Hi, I've already suggested solution to add another component with higher flex value. Updated answer with code snippet for better understanding. Hope that helps you get the overall idea for implementing common `header`